# Why is the SQL index going to the wrong column?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

So here is the snippet of code I am having trouble with:

```
while(rs.next()){
            if(qu==rs.getInt(1)){
                for(int a=0; a<7; a++){
                    System.out.printf("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s", rs.getDouble(2), budgets[a][qu], (rs.getDouble(2)-budgets[a][qu]), (rs.getDouble(2)-budgets[a][qu])/budgets[a][qu] );
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
        }
```

I have a table in MySQL of these values:

```
id|sales

1   12  
2   -99
3   -99
4   -99
```

But when ever I run the method rs.getInt(1)(Where rs is the ResultSet), I get values from the "sales" column, and not the "id" column. Am I using the method wrong? Can anyone tell me how to take data from the id/1st column?

Comment: Do the column indexes begin at 0? eg the first column is `rs.GetDouble(0)`, the second column is `rs.GetDouble(1)`.

Comment: No, SQL indexes start with 1.

Comment: Fair comment!! What order does your SQL statement list the fields in? That's the only other way I can think they would get swapped over.

Comment: That was the problem! That really went by me. You can post an answer if you would like, if others are having the same problem as me :-)

Comment: Glad I could help :0) Will post an answer now - thanks ;O)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As identified by the OP, it was the underlying SQL query that had a different column order to the database table.

It was definitely not the column indexes beginning at 0 since as the OP points out, they start at 1 in MySql ;O)